# How to select rows from MySQL table only if count of rows matching index meets value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return rows from a MySQL table only if the count of the number of rows matching an index meets a certain number.

Here's the issue: I have a table of user reviews that are indexed by username. Therefore, I have many rows with different reviews all indexed by usernames. I am creating a search filter, so I need to return the usernames of people who have a certain number of reviews (ie. number of review rows in the table).

How would I create a MySQL query that would pull only usernames of people say that have 4 reviews (4 table row entries)?

Comment: know that u dont loose anything to post your table schema and your sql and what have you tried and let others help you in the good way

Comment: Thanks goodmood, normally I would do that, just didn't have any idea where to start on the query. Will do next time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds to be a simple `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` aggregate using a `HAVING` clause to limit to those with 4 reviews.

```
SELECT
  username,
  COUNT(*) AS num_reviews
FROM
  user_reviews
GROUP BY username
/* Limit to those with 4 reviews */
HAVING num_reviews = 4
```

Review the [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) reference for information on how `GROUP BY` is used.  The `HAVING` clause is applied after the `GROUP BY` and is used to limit its results.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9dc86/1

Comment: Thank you so much Michael, really appreciate that. Quick question I forgot to mention - How can I make it so that it select 4 or GREATER reviews? Thank you!!

Comment: @Arun `HAVING num_reviews >= 4`